# How to display the error message of a custom validator?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a custom validator, which looks like this:

```js
export class TestRequestComponent implements OnInit {
  noSymptomSelected: boolean = true;
  symptoms: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    symptom1: new FormControl(false),
    symptom2: new FormControl(false),
    symptom3: new FormControl(false)
  }, this.validateMe)
  
  form = this.fb.group({
    symptoms: this.symptoms
  })

  validateMe(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    if (Object.values(control.value).some((e) => e === true)) {
      return { error: true };
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Now I would like to display its error message. This is what I have tried:

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['symptoms']?.errors['validateMe']">ERROR! At least 1 checkbox should be selected.</mat-error>
```

But I get this error:

> TS2533: Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['symptoms']?.errors?.['validateMe']">ERROR! At least 1 checkbox should be selected.</mat-error>
```

You forgot a `?.` between `errors` and `['validateMe']`

Comment: The error is gone now but now my custom error is not getting displayed at all.

Comment: Yes, because form.controls.symptoms.value doesn't have any value to true.
Meaning symptoms.value.symptom1, symptoms.value.symptom2 and symptoms.value.symptom3 are set to false. Try changing one to true to see the error.

Also, you need to change "validateMe" to "error" as the errors object will contain the "error" key with true as value

`<mat-error *ngIf="form.controls['symptoms']?.errors?.['error']">ERROR! At least 1 checkbox should be selected.</mat-error>`

Comment: When validator detects error, the `symptoms.errors` property will be set to validator's return value `{ error: true }`, not {validateMe: true}. It's better if validator returns meaningful value like {notChecked: 'At least 1 checkbox should be selected' }, not generic 'error'. Then you check for error in template with `*ngIf="form.controls.symptoms.hasError('notChecked')"`